# Monitors into sleep mode and out of sleep mode with and app

Tags: display, app

I work in a factory and we have several monitors attached to PC's throughout the shop that stay "ON" 24/7/365.

I want to be able to send the monitors into sleep mode or awaken them from sleep mode from my computer.

How can I accomplish this task easily?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Natively a monitor does not have any external brains, so will not receive external commands.

Either leave it on, or set it to go black after the longest time interval.

Consider a smart power bar (out of scope for this forum) that can be turned on and off remotely. Connect the monitor to this smart power bar.

Answer (score 0):

You may use
[psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
to send commands to the computers to turn off the monitor.

This will require writing a batch script that will cycle through
a text list of the computers and send a command to turn off their
monitors.

See the article
[Turn Off Monitor Using Shortcut or Command-line in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/turn-off-monitor-shortcut-command-windows/)
for various methods and utilities for turning off the monitor.
Perhaps the simplest method is to use this PowerShell command:

```
powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)
```

Note that any user activity on a compute whose monitor is turned off
will automatically turn the monitor back on.

Comment: I want to be able to turn the monitor to sleep mode or awaken it from sleep mode.

Comment: (1) To awaken from sleep, change the last parameter in the command from `2` to `-1`. (2) The utilities described in the article also all have parameters to undo the sleep.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI CEC commands https://www.pulse-eight.com/p/104/usb-hdmi-cec-adapter
[image]

[image]

So this device is a pass-through and only injects CEC commands.

Standby is one of the options, but many other options not listed here exist.